# sublime 3 autocomplete awkward to complete

Tags: python, sublimetext3

Sorry if this has a simple answer, but I'm stumped how to find it. 
In Sublime3 (on Mac), I really like the autocomplete. For example, in Python, if I type:

```
print('
```

it automatically makes the second quote and bracket for me.
However, when I'm done typing inside the quotes, I have to push

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>

It's not terrible, but it's awkward enough that it slows down my typing. Is there a faster way to jump to the next line in this situation?

Comment: We could hook you up with a key binding other than that one that jumps you to the end of the line or one that will jump the cursor to the end of the line and then press enter for you; is that the sort of thing you're looking for here?

Comment: @OdatNurd Yeah, that's sounds like it would work for me. Basically I really just want to be able to jump to the end of the line, when you put it that way. I'd love to know how to go about that.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you can do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>RETURN</kbd>. This will put you into the next line, keeping the automatically inserted quotes and parantheses where they belong.

If that doesn't work on your mac, try <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, that works great to jump to the next line. To stay on the same line, though, the fastest thing I found was I can just type the second quote and it types over what's already there, so I don't end up with doubles.

Comment: Wait, you want to stay on the same line? Wouldn't a simple _->_ work? That does the trick for me. If you want to get the the end of the current line, try the _End_ key too, maybe that is what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry my responses are taking so long. Yeah, I want to basically jump to the end of the line. I was able to do it with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>. But it feels kind of awkward. So I want to try what OdatNurd said, about making a key binding.